# angular protractor test how to open test page in firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, protractor

Chrome on my Macbook Pro has been restricted by company policy, so no chrome extensions can be added.

I'm using `protractor` to do `angualrjs` e2e test, and when I run the command to test, Chrome prompts an error dialog:

> Failed to load extension from: /private/var/folders/fs/xrgskh8502ddg026py0f61j9v7q1z6/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.TQYyRX/internal. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.

Now I suppose to have two solutions:

1. Try to bypass the restriction. (still failed to break it yet)
2. Try to change `protractor` to open in other browser, e.g. Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change in your protractor.conf file**

```
capabilities: {
"browserName": "firefox"
},
chromeOnly: false,
```

Comment: hi rajana, thanks for your answer, but now I got another block from firefox. "Security wrapper denied access to property length on privileged Javascript object. Support for exposing privileged objects to untrusted content via __exposedProps__ is being gradually removed - use WebIDL bindings or Components.utils.cloneInto instead. Note that only the first denied property access from a given global object will be reported. index.html:68
Error: Permission denied to access property '0'" , do you know this ?

Comment: what is your firefox version

Comment: Selenium 2.44 is currently not compatible with Firefox 35.

Comment: `chromeOnly` is deprecated, use `directConnect` https://github.com/mitsuruog/generator-angular-mitsuruog/issues/23